# Unity player setting is not accepting package name

Tags: unity-game-engine, bundle-identifier, package-name

In Unity 5.6.0 I am trying to change package name from player setting but it shows default package name again in player setting. When I finish editing package name and click outside of that textfield I can see default package name appearing again. Don't understand whats issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you currently in play mode? If not, after typing your package name, hit the Enter key.

Comment: It's probably the enter key thing. Clicking outside of a text box in the inspector has a bad habit of reverting the value. I have this problem all the time with renaming objects in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Ben Brookes Thanks! I was missing to press enter key. But in lower version of unity I was able to change it by tapping outside of textbox.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help!